# How to read data without specific symbol in python?

Tags: python

My dataset looks like following. I am trying to read numbers in "per" column without reading "%" symbol.Being a beginner in python,I was wondering if we can do such in python. Also, if you could provide the explanation that will be great!

```
State     Year   per
A         1990    6.10%
A         1989    4.50%
B         1990    3.4%
B         1989    1.25%
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. What is your dataset? Is it a CSV file, Pandas dataframe, or something else? Also show us your latest attempt(s).

Comment: Something to get you started: look up slicing. You can pull all values from a string except the last character. Then convert the value to a numeric if you need to.

Comment: If it's a `df` use [strip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) `df['per'] = df.per.str.strip("%").astype(float)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it is a csv file, this should help (or there might be another way to get a dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("somefile.csv")
data["per"] = data["per"].str.replace("%", "").to_numeric()
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your file type doesn't matter for this and no modules required. It works by taking each row and going to the last word. Then it splits the percentage and removes the percent symbol.

```
def readFile(filename):
    percents = []
    with open (filename,"r") as f:
        for row in f:#for each line, we remove the first one late
            splitRow = row.split()[-1]# spliting the elements by word, we want the last one only
            percent = splitRow
            percent = percent.split("%")[0]#removing the percent 
            percents.append(percent)#if you want it as an number instead of a string do percents.append(float(percent))
    percents = percents[1:] # removes the header "per"
    return percents
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. Never thought that  I can achieve this by using function. Thanks!